# Validate text with javascript RegEX

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate text with javascript but can find out why it's not working.

I have been using : https://regex101.com/ for testing where it works but in my script it fails

```
    var check = "test"
    var pattern = new RegExp('^(?!\.)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$(?<!\.)','gmi');
    if (!pattern.test(check)) validate_check = false;else validate_check = true;
```

What i'm looking for is first and last char not a dot, and string may contain [a-zA-Z0-9._-]

But the above check always fails even on the word : test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about more simpler RegEx?

```js
var checks = ["test", "1-t.e_s.t0", ".test", "test.", ".test."];
checks.forEach(check => {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^[^.][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+[^.]$','gmi');
  console.log(check, pattern.test(check))
});
```

Your code should look like this:

```js
var check = "test";
var pattern = new RegExp('^[^.][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+[^.]$','gmi');
var validate_check = pattern.test(check);
console.log(validate_check);
```

Answer (score 1):

`+$(?<!\.)` is invalid in your [RegEx](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions)

1. [`$` will match the end of the text or line](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors) (with the [`m` flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-multiline-mode))
2. [Negative lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead) → `(?<!Y)X` will match `X`, but only if `Y` is **not** before it

Comment: Also, the `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]` is invalid; try using `[\w\.\-]`

Comment: It's not invalid? What makes you think it is? Well, not optimal, but not invalid!

Comment: only `.` should be escaped probably i.e `\.`

Answer (score 0):

A few notes about the pattern:

- You are using the RegExp constructor, where you have to double escape the backslash. In this case with a single backslash, the pattern is `^(?!.)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$(?<!.)` and the first negative lookahead will make the pattern fail if there is a character other than a newline to the right, that is why it does not match `test`
- If you use the `/i` flag for a case insensitive match, you can shorten `[A-Za-z]` to just one of the ranges like `[a-z]` or use `\w` to match a word character like in your character class
- This part `(?<!\.)` using a negative lookbehind is not invalid in your pattern, but is is not always [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)

For your requirements, you don't have to use lookarounds. If you also want to allow a single char, you can use:

```
^[\w-]+(?:[\w.-]*[\w-])?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[\w-]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a word character or `-`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[\w.-]*[\w-]` Match optional word chars, a dot or hyphen
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sIq5dl/1)

```js
const regex = /^[\w-]+(?:[\w.-]*[\w-])?$/;
["test", "abc....abc", "a", ".test", "test."]
.forEach((s) =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
);
```